# Mozilla WebExtension API storage - Debugging with and without breakpoints leads to different output

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

Hello guys,

i am trying to implement an add-on for the Mozilla-Firefox Browser.
The following script shows one backgorund script I already successfully integrated. It uses the Mozilla WebExtension API storage. It gets executed but the log on the browser console suprises me.
I get alternating logged nothing and:

```
bla
bla
bla
```

If and only if I set breakpoints on significant lines (especially the last 5 lines) of my code in Debugging-Mode I get always the expected result:

```
bla
```

How is it that the output depends on setting breakpoints.
I have no idea what is happening and can not find any similar problems on the internet. Can somebody explain to me what is happening and what I can do to prevent the wrong output?
storeManager.js:

```
var localStore = chrome.storage.local;  
var StoreManager = function(){};

StoreManager.prototype.addItem = function(type, item){
    var thisRef = this;

    localStore.get(type, 
        function(obj){
            if(chrome.runtime.lasterror){
                console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
            }else{
                var oldArr = obj[type];

                if(oldArr === undefined)
                    oldArr = [];

                if(oldArr.indexOf(item) !== -1)
                    return;

                oldArr.push(item);
                thisRef.setItem(type, oldArr);
            }
        }
    );
}

StoreManager.prototype.removeItem = function(type, item){
    var thisRef = this;

    localStore.get(type, 
        function(obj){
            if(chrome.runtime.lasterror){
                console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
            }else{
                var oldArr = obj[type];

                if(oldArr === undefined)
                    return;

                var index = oldArr.indexOf(item);
                if(index === -1)
                    return;

                oldArr.splice(index, 1);
                thisRef.setItem(type, oldArr);
            }   
        }
    );
}

StoreManager.prototype.setItem = function(type, item){
    localStore.set({ [type] : item }, 
        function(){
            if(chrome.runtime.lasterror){
                console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
            }
        }
    );
}

StoreManager.prototype.visitItems = function(type, visit){
    localStore.get(type, 
        function(obj){
            if(chrome.runtime.lasterror){
                console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
            }else{
                var oldArr = obj[type];

                if(oldArr !== undefined){
                    for(var i=0; i<oldArr.length; i++){
                        visit(oldArr[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    );
}

function justLog(str){
    console.log(str);
}

var sm = new StoreManager();
sm.visitItems("lol", justLog);
sm.addItem("lol", "bla");
sm.visitItems("lol", justLog);
sm.removeItem("lol", "bla");
sm.visitItems("lol", justLog);
```

manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Addon",
    "version": "0.0",

    "description": "no desc",

    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "storeManager.js"
        ]
    },

    "permissions": [
        "storage"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your *manifest.josn*. On what lines are you setting breakpoints?

Comment: manifest.json and breakpoint lines information added

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`storage.local.set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Storage/StorageArea/set) is asynchronous. The data isn't guaranteed to be visible to a call to [`get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Storage/StorageArea/get) until the callback is invoked (or if you use `browser.storage.local`, `set()` will return a Promise and the data will be guaranteed to be written when that Promise resolves).

Your code is inherently full of race conditions.  The calls to `addItem()` and `removeItem()` are racing against the calls to `visitItems()`, by setting breakpoints you let one path or the other "win" the race.

If you expect deterministic results, I would suggest using the Promise variants of `storage.local` and writing your code as a series of chained handlers.