# browser.storage.local value getting overwritten instead of appended to

Tags: javascript, logging, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to write an asynchronous logger function for use in a Firefox Web extension that writes persistent copies of logged messages in addition to console output. It maintains all previously created logs, naming them using Date() strings. (A rotation mechanism is planned after I get this working).
The Log() function when run, is supposed to append a message to the current log and reflect this in `browser.storage.local.get(window.logFile)`.
However, only the last logged message gets recorded, it overwrites the log with it. Sorry this has so much code, but It can't be looked at with less.

I have tried making the function not asynchronous and not waiting for it. I have discovered that the inner function work(obj) receives an empty object from its promise every time, but I do not know why.

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
    // isEmpty(obj)
    // Checks if an object is empty.
    // EX: var a = {};
    // returns true or false
    if (Object.entries(obj).length === 0) {
        if (obj.constructor === Object) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

async function Log(message, level) {
    // Log(message, level)
    // Primary logging facility for the program
    // Use instead of console.log to allow exportable output
    // Arguments:
    //      message:
    //          A string.
    //      level:
    //          A string. Valid levels are:
    //              "error", "warn", "log", "info", "debug"
    //
    "use strict";
    function work(obj) {
        // Does the actual work, called as onResolve handler for a promise.
        console.log(obj);
        var oldLog;
        var newLog;
        if (!isEmpty(obj)) {
            console.info("Not Empty");
            oldLog = obj[window.logFile];
        } else {
            console.info("empty");
            oldLog = "";
        }

        switch (level) {
            case "error":
                newLog = oldLog + level + ":: " + message + "\n";
                console.error(message);
                browser.storage.local.set({[window.logFile]: newLog});
                break;
            case "warn":
                newLog = oldLog + level + ":: " + message + "\n";
                console.warn(message);
                browser.storage.local.set({[window.logFile]: newLog});
                break;
            case "info":
                newLog = oldLog + level + ":: " + message + "\n";
                console.info(message);
                browser.storage.local.set({[window.logFile]: newLog});
                break;
            case "debug":
                newLog = oldLog + level + ":: " + message + "\n";
                console.debug(message);
                browser.storage.local.set({[window.logFile]: newLog});
                break;
            default:
                newLog = oldLog + level + ":: " + message + "\n";
                console.log(message);
                browser.storage.local.set({[window.logFile]: newLog});
        }
    }


    if (typeof(window.logFile) !== "string") {
        window.logFile = "" + new Date();
        console.log(window.logFile + "\n Program started.");
        let getLogs = browser.storage.local.get("allLogs");
        getLogs.then((obj) => {
            console.log(obj);
            if (!isEmpty(obj)) {
                obj.allLogs.push(window.logFile);
                browser.storage.local.set(obj);
            } else {
                browser.storage.local.set({allLogs: [window.logFile]});
            }
        });
    }

    console.log(window.logFile);
    //browser.storage.local.get(window.logFile).then(work);
    work(await browser.storage.local.get(window.logFile));
}

Log("logger loaded", "debug");
Log("logger should have two messages", "debug");
```

I expect the output of the bottom two calls to produce a value for `browser.storage.local.get(window.logFile)` which contains a string with `"debug:: logger loaded\ndebug:: logger should have two messages"`

However only the second message actually gets written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for wasting time here I found another question that while not quite duplicate pretty much explains it. Basically, the log functions would co-exist creating a race condition. A queue is needed to manage this as the logs running at the same time, have random output as a result of browser.storage.local.get from one log getting called before the other writes its output.
[Other Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38814120/mozilla-webextension-api-storage-debugging-with-and-without-breakpoints-leads/38821081#38821081)